# unable to store whatsapp chat in new account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have just deleted my whatsapp account and now i want to reconfigure my account and i want my previous chats in new account, but the backup of previous chats are not retrieving.
I have also check my database folder it have the chats backup file but still the problem is coming

Can any one help me in this to restore my Chats backup in new account

Answer (score 0):

Use the same phone number as used during the time of backup.
If that doesn't work reinstall Whatsapp.

Comment: its asking for google drive and not taking the previous one

Comment: Is your whatsapp updated?

Comment: yes it is updated

Comment: It is seraching for backup on google account not in my phone storage

Comment: please help me in that i need one of mine previous chat back

Comment: Try older version https://whatsapp-messenger.en.uptodown.com/android/old

Comment: Also, make sure you've pasted Whatsapp folder in the correct storage location